# Azure functions isolated NET 7 Unable to Add-Migration of Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions, .net-7.0

I'm trying to connect Azure Functions (Isolated) with EF Core 7.0.1 using NET 7.

Add-Migration throw an error: Unable to create an object of type 'MyDbContext'.

Error descriptions

[image]

All necessary packages already installed.

Here is my project:
**Folder structure**

[image]

- **MyDbContext**.cs:

**DbContext**

[image]

- **Program.cs**:

Add `DbContext` with correct connection string

[image]

Am I missing something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide code in text/code format.

Answer (score 1):

Database Migrations happen at *Design-Time*, not at *Runtime*. So you have to provide your IDE with a way to create a `DbContext` without starting the actual function. One way would be to implement a *Design Time Factory* as described in the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). With that class created, the command `Add-Migration` automatically finds that class and executes `CreateDbContext`, which then provides the context for the migration.